# How to write a query to find Median of column in a Table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database

I was trying to solve problem in Hackerrank SQL Practice section and stuck in Problem 'Weather Observation Problem 20'.

To find Median, I though of the following approach:

1. sub-query to count the lower half of the entries.
2. sub-query to count the upper half of the entries.
3. Equate these queries together under a WHERE clause (so that an entry has the same number of entries before and after).

QUERY:

```
select round(s.lat_n,4) 
from station s 
where (
        select round(count(s.id)/2)-1 
        from station
    ) = (
        select count(s1.id) 
        from station s1 
        where s1.lat_n > s.lat_n
    );
```

PLEASE HELP ME OUT WITH THE OPTIMIZED QUERY.

LINK OF PROBLEM STATEMENT : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem

Comment: Are you using Oracle MySQL or MariaDB ? What is the exact version used ?

Comment: I am using Oracle MySQL

Comment: too bad: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sort the values the median will be either exactly in the middle (odd number of rows) or the average of two values around the middle (even number of rows). For these values the following is true:

- at least half of all values (including itself) are equal or less
- at least half of all values (including itself) are equal or greater

When you find that/those values (let's call them *candidates*), you will need the average of distinct candidate values.

The abouve can be expressed with the following query:

```
select round(avg(distinct lat_n), 4) as median_lat_n
from station s
cross join (select count(*) as total from station) t
where t.total <= 2 * (select count(*) from station s1 where s1.lat_n <= s.lat_n)
  and t.total <= 2 * (select count(*) from station s1 where s1.lat_n >= s.lat_n)
```

Note that this is a quite slow solution for big tables.

Comment: Thanks Paul for giving the insights !
It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

`Select round(lat_n,4)  from  (select lat_n , rank() over(order by lat_n) as rnk from station )a where  rnk = (select round((count(lat_n)+1)/2,0) as c from station ) ;`

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

/* SQL ERVER */
SELECT LATNR
FROM
(
SELECT CAST(ROUND(LAT_N,4) AS DECIMAL(17,4)) LATNR, RANK() OVER( ORDER BY LAT_N ASC) IDX
FROM STATION
) AS F
WHERE IDX IN ( CEILING (CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) +1 FROM STATION) AS FLOAT) /2 ))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Certmax! Your answer would benefit from better formatting and an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select round(lat_n,4)  
from  (select lat_n , rank() over(order by lat_n) as Rnk_Col 
   from station) as Rnk_Table
where  Rnk_Col = (select round((count(lat_n)+1)/2,0) 
from station);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is more robust than hardcoding the `+1` and more efficient than including an `IF` statement.

```sql
with Tbl as (select row_number() over (order by lat_n) rc, lat_n from station)
select cast(avg(lat_n) as Decimal(15,4)) 
from tbl 
where rc = (select ceiling(max(rc)/2.0) from tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(lat_n,4) from
(SELECT lat_n,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY lat_n) ) as "serial_no"
from station ) AS t1
WHERE  t1.serial_no = (
select (count(*)+1)/2
    from station
)
```

I used row_number() to create a new column in a table that gives a serial number to ascending ordered lat_n and then displayed the median lat_n value corresponding to middle value of row_number.

Answer (score 0):

- First assigns position for each rows using ROW_NUMBER() window function
- Second select the middle row if row count is odd else select the two rows in the middle as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)
- Finally compute the average and round to 4th decimal point.

> If row count is odd, the where conditions return the middle row
>
> Else if row count is even, the where conditions return the two middle rows.

```
WITH POSITIONED AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N ASC) AS ROW_NUM,
        LAT_N
    FROM STATION
)

SELECT ROUND(AVG(LAT_N), 4)
FROM POSITIONED
WHERE ROW_NUM = CEIL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION) / 2) OR 
      ROW_NUM = CEIL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION) / 2 + 0.1)
```